# Labeling a joined (one to many) layer with the number of feature joined to it in ArcGIS Online

Tags: labeling, arcgis-online, attribute-joins, one-to-many

Using ArcGIS Online, I performed a one to many join with a buildings layer (one) and a table of internal cameras (many). This produced a layer showing buildings and allows me to scroll though all the cameras associated with a particular building.

Now, I would like to label the buildings based on the number of cameras joined to a building. For example, a building with 8 cameras would be labeled 8.

I know I will have to populate a field with the number of cameras in each building, but I am not sure how to do this. Any recommendations?